# Am I doing integration correctly? Wolfram alpha has a different answer

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

so im supposed to get the integral of
$$ \int \frac{(1+\sec(x))^2 }{\sec(x)} $$

my solution is

$$= \int \frac{1 + 2\sec (x) + \sec^2(x)}{\sec(x)} dx$$

$$= \int \frac{dx}{\sec (x)} + \int 2\,dx + \int\sec(x) \, dx$$

$$= \int \cos(x)\,dx  + \int 2\,dx + \int\sec(x)\,dx$$

$$= \sin(x) + 2x + \ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)| + C $$

I don't understand why when I double check my answers using an integral solver it doesnt seem to add up

Comment: Everything looks OK.

Comment: What does Wolfram Alpha give as the answer?

Comment: Your question is very vague: you don't tell us specifically what happened when you checked it or what makes you think something doesn't "add up". But I have seen many students thinking that the different-looking correct solutions to problems similar to this are in fact different when they're not. Usually the equality of the two solutions is a trigonometric identity that is not self-evident. Sometimes it's an easy one: one gets $\int\cdots = \tan^2 x+C$ and also $\int\cdots=\sec^2x+C$, and those are the same thing. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy how can I check if the two result of integration are equal without transforming one into the other? Will simply inputing the same value for their variables and checking for equality be enough? thanks in advance

Comment: That they agree at one value of $x$ is not enough.  But why don't you just give us the specifics? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy like one of the answers below when I double check my answers most of the time computation engines give a different form of the answer, Im having a hard time telling whether my answer is really equivalent or if it is truly wrong. Is there an easy way to find out if they are both the correct answer?

Comment: Your answer is right, but if your question is why "double-checking" leads to something that doesn't "add up", then we would need to know more about what you're seeing.

Comment: @MichaelHardy for example in this problem http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%282ln%28x%29+%2B+1%29%2F%28x%28%28lnx%29^2%2Blnx%29 I get ln|(lnx)^2+lnx|+C the solution there looks entirely different with no alternative forms i try getting the derivative of both solutions but both of them still look different

Comment: *Wolfram Alpha has a different answer* - No, it doesn't. Just because an expression “looks” different doesn't mean that it “is” different. $(x+y)^n$ also “looks” different than $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^nx^ky^{n-k}$, but they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram alpha gives answer:

$$\sin(x)+2x+\log(\sin(x/2)+\cos(x/2))-\log(\sin(x/2)-\cos(x/2))$$

But:

$$\ln(\sec(x)+\tan(x))=\ln(\frac{1}{\cos(x)}+\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)})=\\=\ln\left(\frac{1+\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1+\sin(x)}{((\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2))(\cos(x/2)+\sin(x/2))}\right)=\\=\ln\left(\frac{\sin(x/2)^2+\cos(x/2)^2+2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)}{((\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2))(\cos(x/2)+\sin(x/2))}\right)=\\=\ln\left(\frac{\sin(x/2)+\cos(x/2)}{\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2)}\right)=\\=\log(\sin(x/2)+\cos(x/2))-\log(\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2))$$

Comment: @Integrator  is there an easy way to find out whether the two solutions are both correct? would having the same x value and checking for equality be enough?

Comment: @Men It's no sufficient, because you can have two solutions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that $f(x)-g(x)=C$, where $C$ is some constant.

Comment: you can try to ask wolfram to compute  $f(x)-g(x)$ may be it provides a constant.

Comment: You're using two different notations: $\ln$ and $\log$.  I think it's better to pick one and stick with it, lest the reader think they mean two different things. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

your integrand is equivalent to $$\frac{1+\cos(x)^2+2\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}$$ use the substitution
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ and $$dx=\frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2}$$ this is the so called tan half substitution.
your result $$\ln  \left( \sec \left( x \right) +\tan \left( x \right)  \right) +2\,
x+\sin \left( x \right)
$$ is right.